# TVML JS setInterval not working?

Tags: javascript, tvml

I am trying to create a simple slide show app with TVML. I'm trying to use the setinterval function in my javascript functions, but on the tvOS simulator it is not working. When I call the function in a other handler ie App.onWillEnterForeground then my screen refreshes, but not on a timed interval. Anybody aware of the TVML limitations? Or how to solve this?

I don't see the screen updated but also on the webserver I do not see any request.

```js
function MyStartup(){
    var alert = createAlert("Hello", "Welcome to tvOS");
    navigationDocument.pushDocument(alert);
        var interval = setInterval(MyInterval(), 5000);
}

function MyInterval(){
    var newDoc = createAlert("Hello", "Welcome to tvOS");
    const oldMain = navigationDocument.documents[0];
    navigationDocument.replaceDocument(newDoc, oldMain);

}

var createAlert = function(title, description) {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    var alertString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <document>
                <mainTemplate>
                    <background>
                        <img src="http://localhost:9001/IMG_8066.jpg" />
                    </background>
                    <menuBar>
                        <nowPlayingMenuItem>
                            <title>${n}</title>
                        </nowPlayingMenuItem>
                        <section>
                            <menuItem></menuItem>
                        </section>
                    </menuBar>
                </mainTemplate>
        </document>`
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var alertDoc = parser.parseFromString(alertString, "application/xml");
    return alertDoc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think setInterval does work. but you are calling it wrong there.

instead of

`var interval = setInterval(MyInterval(), 5000);`

I think you should left the `()` out and call it as

`var interval = setInterval(MyInterval, 5000);`

You are trying to pass the reference(? or whatever it is call in JS), to the call back function; However you are passing the RETURN VALUE of the function MyInterval() (which is null?) into the callback, so the callback did nothing.